# changed IP on one computer, other computers not picking up new address

Tags: networking, dns, lan

I recently gave one of my desktop computers a static IP to resolve an IP address conflict. One of my laptops picks up the new address immediately, but two of my other computers are still getting the old one when I try to ping the computer by its host name. This has never happened before.

I tried flushing the DNS resolver cache, but it didn't help. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a DHCP server and is it part of a router?

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have any names defined in your `hosts` file?

Comment: what operating system are we talking about here? Was a garp sent over the wire?

Comment: The DHCP server is part of the router. The computer whose IP address I changed is running Windows XP, and so is the laptop that was able to pick up the new address. The other computers are running Windows 7 and Mac OS X.